# How to verify a Token before I render a Home Page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am struggling with a re-render in my project. First, I'm checking a cookie before I redirect the user to the login page. I am using Redux Store with this structure.

```
var initialState = {
    user: {
        auth: false,
        isFetching: false,
        isTokenFetching: false
    }
}
```

Fetching is for login via **login form**, Token fetching is for login via a **Token in cookies**

I'm using a customized Dynamic route to make it render based on this condition. (isFetching is when token is fetching)

```
const DynamicRoute = ({isFetching,isAuthenticated, ...rest}) => {
    return isFetching ? <h1>Fetching</h1> : (
        <Route {...rest} render={(props) =>{
        return isAuthenticated ?
        <HomePage/> :
        <LogInPage/>}}/>
    )
}
```

This function is called before the action is dispatched, So it Renders **LogInPage** first, and **Fetching** when action is dispatched, and Render **HomePage** again when the token is valid.

How can I make sure it only renders the **LogInPage** and **HomePage** once.
For example if token is valid (HomePage only), if token invalid (LogInPage only)

I want this dynamic route to work because I hope to use an URL for both condition.

Sorry if my explanation is bad

Answer (score 3):

1. First, if `isAuthenticated` is true, we should redirect user to `HomePage`, shouldn't we?

```
return isAuthenticated ? <HomePage/> : <LogInPage/>;
```

2. > How can I make sure it only renders the LogInPage and HomePage once.

Use `Redirect` component to redirect user back to `LogInPage` like this:

```
return isAuthenticated ? <HomePage/> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
```

You can get the `Redirect` component from `react-router-dom`:

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
```

I assume that you have defined router like this:

```
<Route path="/login" component={LogInPage} />
```

3. IMHO, you should change the way to authenticate your workflow, because it is not good to scale for the future. Have a look at this: [react-router auth-worflow example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

Basically, your routers will become something like:

```
<Route path="/login" component={LogInPage} />
<PrivateRoute path="/home" component={HomePage} />
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Keep hacking!

Comment: Hi, Yes.. This approach should be working.. if I have different route like **/login /home**.
But what I want to achieve is using a same path for example "/" I can render component based on "IsAuthenticated". If it is **Authenticated** it will render HomePage, else LogInPage, but in same url like **localhost:3000/** for both situation
**Situation now**
isAuthenticated = false -> true(token verified)
Render = LoginPage -> HomePage
How can I wait for token verification before start rendering
**Expected**
isAuthenticated = false -> true(token verified)
Render = HomePage (If token is valid)

Comment: Hm, sorry but I have no idea how to achieve that. IMHO, it's really a bad practice that one `Route` represents for two components like this case. As I couldn't see any advantages of your current approach, I honestly suggest that you should consider on splitting your routes as I recommended above. It's not my own approach but react-router team's.

Comment: Please feel free to post your questions here if you get any issues while switching to the new approach! Keep hacking!